# Not able to click out side of the drop-down - selenium angular

Tags: angular, selenium, dropdown

`Angular 11.0.2` web application

To check if validation message is displayed or not when value is not selected from the drop-down, I am clicking outside of the drop-down, but getting **ElementNotInteractableException**

Also In the inspector window, I am not able to inspect any of the elements when the drop-down is visible.
Getting `div.cdk-overlay-backdrop cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing` when trying to inspect.

Please find the below screenshot for same.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of handling it, either you can click outside of the drop down using a different elements tag name
or use seleniums mouse click action using co-ordinates (Ex: 0,0) whivh is outside of the drop down.

1. `driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).click();`
2. `Actions action = new Actions(driver); action.moveByOffset(0, 0).click().build().perform();`